# Error creating compact sql database file from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

While creating compact sql database file from a model(edmx) showing following error-

There is no store type corresponding to the EDM type '{0}' of primitive type '{1}'.

I can't quiet get the error.

Please help..........

Answer (score 3):

.net Time entity data type is not supported in sql ce3.5, instead used datetime and this is resolve the issue.

Thanks

Ashish